# Have a class deploy a module in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I've read a lot of different sources, and I just can't decide what is the best way to handle deployment of modules to nodes/hosts nor have I gotten some of them to work.
I have created everything in modules.

That being said, when I was testing I was deploying the modules like this;

```
node 'basetesting' {
        include fail2ban
        include nrpe
}

node 'test-dev' inherits 'basetesting' {
}
```

However, I've created a lot of modules and realized that my servers will vary on what their role is (application, web, etc). There is a set of base requirements all of them have. 
So I essentially want a node to have the base. Then have their required modules, which I believe would look something like this;

```
node 'basetesting' {
        include fail2ban
        include nrpe
}

node 'test-dev' inherits 'basetesting' {
            include httpd
}
```

Then I realized ... that I would have to make a definition for every single node. Which, I guess wouldn't be bad, but I imagine if you had 50+ servers, that might become quite the nodes.pp file.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What would be your preferred way to set up the nodes?  Hiera might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is regexing the node names:

node 'www\d.domain.com' inherits 'webserver' {}

That way all of my www1, www2, www3, etc get the right setup. Using descriptive server names also makes it easier for new people to understand how your system as a whole works.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer. Our server naming -- is, well. If I tried to regex them, it would not go over well. :P It's more of a server1, server2, server3 kind of naming convention. Thanks for the tip, though! If I ever implement it in another environment this is good knowledge to have! Much appreciated.

Comment: Another possible method is to use hiera to look up details of a server configuration from a database. At some point you have to describe what each server is doing so you can apply the correct configuration. Using naming conventions do that makes life a lot easier.